# How to keep the hyperlink while using =QUERY formula in google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, formula

I wrote a =QUERY formula in Google spreadsheet.  However I would like to copy not only the values of the cells but also the embedded links from the range of cells I am performing the query on.   This is what I wrote:

```
=QUERY('Tab'!6:1963,"select C where (E='Major' and D >= now())")
```

There must be a way to tell the query to bring the URL as well along the content of the cells.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `query` function only supports [certain data types](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage):

> Supported data types are string, number, boolean, date, datetime and timeofday.

It doesn't handle other things one might embed into a spreadsheet, such as images or hyperlinks. (Hyperlinks are coerced to strings.) After all, the query language is not something Sheets-specific, it has its own data models that  interact with Sheets only to an extent.

A solution is to use `filter` instead of `query`, if possible. It can do many of the things that `query` does. For example,

```
=QUERY(Tab!6:1963,"select C where (E='Major' and D >= now())")
```

can be replaced by

```
=filter(Tab!C6:C1963, (Tab!E6:E1963="Major") * (Tab!D6:D1963 >= now()))
```

which will return the links as expected. (And even images inserted with `=image()` if you got them.) The multiplication operator is logical *and* in the filter formula.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is three years later, but I ran into this issue and my query would have converted to a complicated nest of FILTER and SORT functions. So I ended up doing something like this: `ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(QUERY('Tab'!6:1963,"select C where (E='Major' and D >= now())"),C:C,1,FALSE))`
Which worked.

Answer (score 1):

Often this question comes into play with `IMPORTRANGE`. And Google's official [answer](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/6531120?hl=en) does not really help (i.e. `QUERY` only works with strings, etc.). It is possible to give the filter range as an imported range, too, then it works:

```
=FILTER(IMPORTRANGE("XXX","Data!A1:A),
IMPORTRANGE("XXX","Data!B1:B")>0)
```

where column `A` is the data you want to import and column `B` is the filter